# Fading one div into another

Tags: javascript, wordpress, fade

I'm having some slight problems with fading one div into another, here's my code (and [test page](http://teamworksdesign.com/v2/tags/design/branding/)):

HTML:

```
<div id="grid">
    <div class="grid-box">
        <div class="phase-1">
           <img class="grid-image" src="http://teamworksdesign.com/v2/wp-content/themes/default/images/dtr.jpg" alt="" height="152" width="210" />
           <div class="grid-heading">
                <h2>DTR Medical</h2>
                <h3>Branding, Web, Print</h3>
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="phase-2">
            <div class="grid-info">
                <h4>Probeything 2000</h4>
                <p>Marketing unglamorous single-use medical intruments is not simple. We helped Neurosign increasetheir sales by 25% and increasemarket awareness.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-heading-hover">
                <h2>DTR Medical</h2>
                <h3>Branding, Web, Print</h3>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

$(document).ready(function(){
            $(".phase-2").hide();
        });


$(function(){
$('.grid-box').hover(
        function(){
            $('.grid-box .phase-1').fadeOut(200, function(){
                $('.grid-box .phase-2').fadeIn(200);                         
            });
        },
        function(){
            $('.grid-box .phase-2').fadeOut(200, function(){
                $('.grid-box .phase-1').fadeIn(200);                         
            });
        }
        ); 
});
</script>
```

CSS:

```
.phase-1 .grid-image {
    width:210px;
    height:220px;
    overflow:hidden;    
    }

.phase-2 {
    position:relative;
    top:-220px;
    }
```

UPDATE:
I have one "working" (see test link in question). Is it possible to stop it fading to white then fading in the next phase? I want to fade the two div into each other rather than to white first.

Comment: What are we looking at on the test page? What is happening and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: looks like `$` is being overridden in the page and no longer points to jQuery.

Comment: Sorry, the thumbnail is what I want to fade. D'oh, I guess that might do it! Totally forgot I removed it for the Nivo slide on another page!

Comment: Right, the fade is now working so it's just a case of playing with it to get it right, cheers!

Comment: I have one "working" (see test link in question). Is it possible to stop it fading to white then fading in the next phase? I want to fade the two div into each other rather than to white first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you type `$` on the console, it answer `undefined`, so it probably was redefined by some other script. To use `$` meaning jQuery again, use the following syntax

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    // $ means jQuery again in here
});
```

Notice the `$` as the first argument of the function call.

Documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Comment: I have one "working" (see test link in question). Is it possible to stop it fading to white then fading in the next phase? I want to fade the two div into each other rather than to white first.

Comment: just call both fades simultaneosly, and not on the callback:

Comment: you shouldn't unaccept, you turned this in a different question. just go ahead and make another question on stackoverflow. im not your personal tech support.

Comment: Cheers. It's more of a continuation of the question. I'll have people on my back for asking a similar question like before. Sometimes you can't win on here!

Comment: rob, you can ask as many questions as you like, this and this other question are similar, but not the same. nobody will harass you for that, on the other hand changing the question to something that wasn't the first question is not a good practice at all.